# I can't get an indexed item from my AngularJS resource

Tags: angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
.controller( 'AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ( $scope, $location, $resource ) {
    var Card = $resource('http://localhost/card/:cardId',
      {
        'cardId': "@_id"
      },
      {
      getAll: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) {
          return angular.fromJson(data)._items;
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });

    $scope.allCards = Card.getAll();
    console.log($scope.allCards);
    console.log($scope.allCards[0]);
```

Now, on the console, the two printed lines show:

```
[$resolved: false, $then: function]
    > 0: c
    > 1: c
    > 2: c
    > 3: c
    > 4: c
    > 5: c
    > 6: c
    > 7: c
    > 8: c
    > 9: c
    > 10: c
    > 11: c
    > 12: c
    > 13: c
      $resolved: true
    > $then: function (callback, errback) {
      length: 14
    > __proto__: Array[0]
```

as the value of $scope.allCards, but 'undefined' as the value of $scope.allCards[0].
I can pass $scope.allCards to an ng-repeat, but I want to pick out items by index, and assumed that I would get an array with which I could do this.

What kind of object is my method on 'Card' returning, and how do I get the array from it?

Comment: I'm looking to have access to the 14-item array that appears to be in there.

Comment: maybe it returns an actual promise

Comment: That's it. Sorry, I'm pretty new to JS, didn't know anything about promises...

Comment: I'll add that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isArray: true` methods will return you a promise, you can't act on them directly.

You can pass it a function.

`var cards = Card.getAll(function () { cards[0]; });`